# pyspark: convert a bytearray field to string in data frame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a parquet file to a dataframe:

```
my_df = sqlContext.read.parquet('hdfs://my_server/user/hive/warehouse/my_db.db/my_table')
```

if I do:

```
my_df.head()
```

I got:

```
Row(id=bytearray(b'00000000000000000000000000000000'), numcores=8, ...)
```

and when I do

```
my_df.show()
```

the first field id looks like:

```
[30 30 30 30 30 3...]
```

How do I change the bytearray field and make it show as a string output? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to change what `head()` returns to you, that's not gonna happen, since the [prototype](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.head) doesn't provide any such functionality:

> head(n=None)